# in php javascript window.location.href not working on submit button?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

In PHP JavaScript `window.location.href` is not working on `submit` button. The problem is that function `order()` is not going on submit button. I have tried `alert('');` message also.

I want when order button submitted, then form submits and user is redirected to login.php

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function order() {
    var sStr1 = "login.php";
    window.location.href = sStr1;
    return false;
  }
</script>

<input type="submit" class="button4" name="order" id="order" value="Place Order" onclick="order()" >
```

Comment: What output did you get on submit?

Comment: Try using onclick="javascript:return order()"

Comment: @HarishAnchu nothing just form submitted onclick submit

Comment: Hmm if you aren't actually submitting a form why are you using a submit button?

Comment: problem is that function order() not going on submit button even i have tried alert(''); message also

Comment: @james i want when order button submit then form submit and user redirect to login.php

Comment: @AkberHussain What's your "form action", if you want to submit the form then why are you doing it like this. Submit the form normally by providing the form action and from that page navigate the user to login page.

Comment: is the function being called...try adding a alert as first line, and also check if the new href location is valid

Comment: This used to be possible but I believe now it doesn't work at all in any browser.  Either AJAX your form and then load the new URL or have your server-side code redirect the browser after it has processed the form data.

Comment: @aj alert message also not working

Comment: @RavinderSingh form action="confirm.php"> in confirm.php there is mail function code

Comment: @AkberHussain Do you think that this javascript function will submit the form then you are wrong, this can only navigate the user to login page and use window.location

Comment: Just don't call the order function onclick on submit function, navigate the user from confirm.php page.

Comment: @AkberHussain: that means the call itself is not working, try onclick="var x = order()" in the submit tag. I m not sure but might work since it constraints the false to the var x.

Comment: thats wierd..the function itself is not gettin invoked!!!try removing the return part and see if u get an alert then.

Answer (score 0):

Changing `window.location` does not submit a form. I'd rather type `<form action="login.php" method="...">` and then Javascript is not necessary.

Comment: javascript is neccessary because when submit button click then form will go to another page

Comment: I don't understand. If you want to submit the form, you just click the submit button and the browser does redirecting to the file specified in `action` attribute and sends all form fields. If you change `window.location` you will redirect but no sending occurs.

Answer (score 0):

You must add the redirect script in your server side code. Form must have a action url so that it will be submitted to the url by default submit click (ie, without your *order()* function). Inside that action url check if form data is recieved by

```
if(isset($_POST['order']))
```

and redirect the user inside that condtion as u need.