# button onclick call javascript function not working

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Im trying to call a function when user clicks on the navbar search button but it does not seem to call the javascript fuction and just loads the same page. I have looked at examples and other questions but I dont see anyhing wrong.. Any help would be much appreciated, Here is my code, It is in my Masterpage.aspx:

```
           <div class='navbar-form navbar-left' role='search'>
                    <div class='inputgroup'>
                         <input class='form-control' id='navinput' type='text' placeholder='Search'/>
                         <button class='btn btn-default' type='submit' id='navsearchbtn' runat='server' onclick='NavToSearch();'>
                             <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-search'></span>
                        </button>
                    </div>       
                </div>
```

Here is my Js code (also in Masterpage.aspx):  I just have the test redirect to see if it works. (The code that i want to implement is in comments please check that is okay as well, I then want to use the input text to search database)

```
  <script type='text/javascript'>                   
             function NavToSearch() {
                 window.location.href = 'Search.aspx';

                        /*var navsearchText = $('$navinput').text();

                    if (navsearchText == '')
                    {
                        $('$navinput').attr('placeholder', 'Enter Search Text');
                        return false;
                    }
                    else window.location.href = 'Search.aspx'; */
             }
 </script>
```

UPDATED script/function:

```
 <script type='text/javascript'>
 function NavToSearch()
                 {                     
                 var navsearchText = $('#navinput').text();

                 if (navsearchText == '')
                 {
                     $('#navinput').attr('placeholder', 'Enter Search Text');
                     return false;
                 }
                 else {
                     window.location.href = 'Search.aspx';
                     //return false;
                 }

                     /*OR
                         $(document).ready(function(){
                             var url = "OrderHistory.aspx";
                             $(location).attr('href',url);
                         })*/                            
             }
        </script>
```

Comment: What you expect from your button to do? submit form or call `NavToSearch() ` or the both?

Comment: Just to call/run the function NavToSearch() so I can use/save input and redirect to the Search.aspx page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If youwant just to call the `NavToSearch()` when the button clicked you have to change the type of the button from `submit` to `button` :

```
<button class='btn btn-default' type='button' id='navsearchbtn' runat='server' onclick='NavToSearch();'>
      <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-search'></span>
</button>
```

In your commented code you have to replace `$` sign by `#` for the id `navinput`  and also `.text()` by `.val()` :

```
$('#navinput').val();
```

Instead of :

```
$('$navinput').text();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for commented code,  Ive tried both onclick() and submit (Im not sure if Im doing the submit correctly though) but I get the same result in which the current page is just reloaded (ie No redirect)

Comment: You're welcome, if you want _Just to call/run the function NavToSearch()_ you have to change a button type to `buttton` instead of submit check my updated answer.

Comment: I have replaced the $ with # and it works for the "" input and gives the correct placeholder.  BUT when text is added and I click the page does not even reload.  Whats the problem?

Comment: Okay update the code in your question with the changes you made and i'll check.

Comment: You're welcome brother, you  have just to change `$('#navinput').text();` by `$('#navinput').val();` and it will work gracefully (check my updated answer). if the answer help you vote it up, if the answer is really what you looking for mark it as correct answer, GOOD LUCK.

Comment: Thanks so much, it worked!   For readers:  remember return false; at both the if AND else.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you are using Asp.net Web Forms, if true, your page will have a `form` element, then for a `button` with `type=submit` will trigger the form submit by default, generally this will redirect to your current page.

You can avoid this by `return false` in the click handler:

```
         function NavToSearch() {
             window.location.href = 'Search.aspx';

                    /*var navsearchText = $('$navinput').text();

                if (navsearchText == '')
                {
                    $('$navinput').attr('placeholder', 'Enter Search Text');
                }
                else window.location.href = 'Search.aspx'; */

             return false; //prevent the form submit whatever.
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

For a submit button, either the form submission will cancel the redirect, or the redirect will cancel the submission if `return false` is added after.

Check this question:

[How do I redirect users after submit button click?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15220339/how-do-i-redirect-users-after-submit-button-click)